# Get sizeof type that is pointed to by a typedefed pointer

Tags: c, sizeof

I have code that looks like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct SomeStruct* ptr;
main(){
  printf("%lu\n",sizeof(ptr));
}
```

The given code will print the size of `struct SomeStruct*`. However I want `sizeof(struct SomeStruct)`. If I don't know beforehand the name of the struct, is there a way for me to still find the size of the struct pointed to by `ptr`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a variable with type `ptr`, you can dereference it:

```
ptr v;
sizeof(*v)
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me. I get an error saying `expected expression before ptr`

Comment: Joining the quesion - this doesn't compile.

Comment: sorry, I didn't read it carefully, I thought you have a pointer variable

Answer (score 5):

Since `NULL` is a variable which can be converted to type `ptr`, simply use that:

```
sizeof *(ptr)NULL
```

Alternatively, you can avoid the ugly practice of typedef-ing pointers, and this problem dissappears altogether.